# Is there a way to optimize function thresholds with fixed steps?

Tags: python, optimization, minimize, scipy-optimize

How can I optimize a function with fixed steps? I have developed a function with five thresholds as entry that I want to optimize. I actually tried to optimize them with different solvers, but the steps that the solver takes are so tiny that the function never converge in a good solution.

Defined thresholds vary from 0 to 1, and I want them to take steps of 0.01. For example, in case of threshold_0, I want It to vary from initial guess 0.6 to 0.61 or 0.59, etc. depending on error result.

```
from scipy import optimize
initial_guess = [0.6,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.5]

def get_sobel3d_accuracy_from_thresholds(thresholds,array_dicts,ponderation_dict):
    ...
    return error

result = optimize.minimize(
            get_sobel3d_accuracy_from_thresholds, # function to optimize
            initial_guess,
            args=(array_dicts,ponderation_dict), # extra fixed args
            method='nelder-mead',
            options={'xatol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

What I want to get is a solution that minimizes de error returned from the function `get_sobel3d_accuracy_from_thresholds` as follows:

```
optimized_thresholds = [0.61, 0.3, 0.81, 0.52, 0.44]
```

I would also like to fix boundaries for thresholds from 0 to 1, but I think that It can be done only with some solvers, right?

```
bounds = [(0, 1) for n in range(0,5)]
```

thank you all.